# why setTimeout dont work in my code? I need workable code)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know why my code dont work. Please help!

```
$('nav').mouseout(setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('subm')
}, 1000));
```

Without setTimeout is work normaly.

Comment: You're calling the setTimeout, not passing it to mouseout.

Comment: Think about what value `mouesout` expects and which value `setTimeout` returns. Also think about what `this` will be inside the callback.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout(...)` is being called immediately. It returns the id number of the newly pending timeout. The timeout is only registered and called once here. The execution of your code is happening like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('subm')
}, 1000);
// = 2

$('nav').mouseout(2);
```

You need to pass .mouseout() a function that calls setTimeout each time. You also need to fix the `this` reference, which is different inside the setTimeout callback. This should fix both issues:

```
$('nav').mouseout(function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(self).removeClass('subm')
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, like in most other languages, when you do this:

```
variable = some_function();
```

you're passing the return value of a function to a variable. Similarly when you do this:

```
a_function(another_function());
```

you're passing the return value of another function as an argument to a function.

This works the same in javascript, C, PHP, Ruby and even Fortran.

So, when you do this:

```
$('nav').mouseout(setTimeout(..));
```

You're passing the return value of `setTimeout` as an argument to `mouseout`. And `setTimeout` returns a number which can be used in `clearTimeout`. So you're basically doing this:

```
$('nav').mouseout(a_number);
```

What you want instead is to pass a function:

```
$('nav').mouseout(function(){setTimeout(..)});
```

Or if you find that hard to read then do this:

```
function handleMouseOut () {
    setTimeout(...);
}
$('nav').mouseout(handleMouseOut); // note we're passing a function here
                                   // not calling it
```